# Generate apk file for meteor app

Tags: meteor, apk

I have a project is working for android browser. Is there a way to generate the apk file?
Also, are there anything that I shoud know before generating the apk file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can build an APK file with `meteor build` command.

Read more about it in the docs: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteorbuild or by typing `meteor help build` in your terminal.

Answer (score 34):

There are a few steps to follow in order to generate the Android application file (`.apk`) from a meteor app:

1. `meteor install-sdk android`
2. Have the `mobile-config.js` file in your project root ([mobile-config.js example](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#submitting-android))
3. `meteor add-platform android`
4. `meteor build ~/your-output-dir --server=yourapp.meteor.com`

Then you will have your `.apk` file in `~/your-output-dir/android/unaligned.apk`

If you want to proceed and submit to Google Play Store, here are the steps to follow:  https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#submitting-android

Hope this helps!

Comment: >meteor install-sdk android


This command is not yet available on Windows.

>meteor add-platform android
C:\Users\hifi\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.6.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:218
      throw error;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module 'dezalgo'

Comment: I ran all 4 steps, not able to find android/unaligned.apk, got myapp.tar.gz which on extracted created bundle folder which contains: $ ls bundle/
main.js  programs  README  server  star.json

Comment: $ meteor build ../build --server=localhost:3000 I ran this command

Comment: @AshishKarpe Make sure you have one `android` line in the `.meteor/platforms` file.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with Meteor 1.2, the bundled Android tools have been removed and a system-wide install of the Android SDK is now required. This should make it easier to keep the development toolchain up to date and helps avoid some difficult to diagnose failures. The meteor install-sdk command no longer attempts to download and install the Android tools for you (it has been deprecated and just points you to these instructions).

Answer (score 1):

like imslavko says, `meteor build` works pretty fine, also if you are looking for more information take a look on this [Meteorpedia](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Mobile_support)

It work for me

Reegards

Comment: Both the answer and the Meteorpedia link are deprecated as of Meteor 1.2

Answer (score 0):

As of now playstore has started giving warning while uploading APK about unoptimised bundle and insisting for uploading Android app bundle.
Insted of generating APK why not generate .aab of your project and reduce size of the application.

For people wondering about how to generate .aab for your existing project can read my blog here:

[My blog link](https://medium.com/fasal-engineering/generate-aab-android-application-bundle-from-meteor-project-629f5d622c93)