# Meteor: Cannot find the ANDROID_HOME when I try to build via Ubuntu even though I set the correct path

Tags: android, ubuntu, meteor, android-sdk-tools

I try to build my Meteor project for Android. As seen in:

[Generate apk file for meteor app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617869/generate-apk-file-for-meteor-app#29935744)

Therefore on my Ubuntu machine I installed the android SDK from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html Where it says: *"Get just the command line tools"*. The installation path is the `/home/pcmagas/Λήψεις/tools` containing the following files:

```
drwxr-xr-x 6 pcmagas pcmagas   4096 Ιούλ 19 11:43 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 pcmagas pcmagas   4096 Ιούλ 19 11:43 ../
-rwxr--r-- 1 pcmagas pcmagas   4741 Μάρ  29 00:46 android*
drwxr-xr-x 2 pcmagas pcmagas   4096 Μάρ  29 00:46 bin/
-rwxr--r-- 1 pcmagas pcmagas 643536 Μάρ  29 00:46 emulator*
-rwxr--r-- 1 pcmagas pcmagas 394336 Μάρ  29 00:46 emulator-check*
drwxr-xr-x 6 pcmagas pcmagas   4096 Μάρ  29 00:46 lib/
-rwxr--r-- 1 pcmagas pcmagas  12191 Μάρ  29 00:46 mksdcard*
-rwxr--r-- 1 pcmagas pcmagas   1257 Μάρ  29 00:46 monitor*
-rw-r--r-- 1 pcmagas pcmagas 629709 Μάρ  29 00:46 NOTICE.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pcmagas pcmagas    919 Ιούλ 19 11:43 package.xml
drwxr-xr-x 7 pcmagas pcmagas   4096 Μάρ  29 00:46 proguard/
-rw-r--r-- 1 pcmagas pcmagas    139 Μάρ  29 00:46 source.properties
drwxr-xr-x 2 pcmagas pcmagas   4096 Μάρ  29 00:46 support/
```

Also I exported the `ANDROID_HOME` enviromental variable with this value:

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME
/home/pcmagas/Λήψεις/tools
```

And `PATH` variable into this:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME
```

Then I `cd` my meteor project and I give the following command:

```
meteor add-platform android
```

But I get the following error:

```
✗ Android target: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
✗ Gradle: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
  Looked here: /home/pcmagas/Λήψεις/tools/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper
```

I also tried:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/bin"
```

Still no success.

## Edit 1:

Please keep in mind that I have already seen the:

- [Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613882/error-could-not-find-gradle-wrapper-within-android-sdk-might-need-to-update-yo)
- [Cordova: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42645285/cordova-android-sdk-not-found-make-sure-that-it-is-installed-if-it-is-not-at#42805031)

Still no success.

## Edit 2:

I run:

```
sdkmanager "build-tools;25.0.3"
```

And now I get the only error:

```
✗ Gradle: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
  Looked here: /home/pcmagas/Λήψεις/SDK/tools/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper
```

Furthermore I changed the `ANDROID_HOME` into`/home/pcmagas/Λήψεις/SDK/tools`
And moved all folders generated by SDK into: `/home/pcmagas/Λήψεις/SDK/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ANDROID_HOME` environmental variable should link directly to your Android SDK folder, not to its `tools` subfolder.

```bash
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/pcmagas/Λήψεις/SDK
```

You may still add the `tools` subfolder (and `platform-tools` if desired) to your PATH:

```bash
PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH"
PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH"
```